# Why is any value saved in a segment register multiplied by 10?

Tags: assembly

In Assembly Language, why is it that any value saved in a segment register is multiplied by 10? I have tried to find the answer in so many books but I didn't.

Comment: Are you talking about real mode programming?  They're not multiplied by 10. They are shifted left 8 bits because they were originally a 16 bit architecture supporting 24 bit addressing.

Answer (score 3):

First, assembly is not a single language nor is the implementation a single thing. You would have to say which architecture you are talking about for anyone to give a proper answer.

Second, segment registers are not multiplied by 10 always. I would even go so far as to say they're never multiplied by 10, since 10 is not a natural number for binary systems.

If you are asking about why, for example, in x86 architecture to get a physical address the CPU multiplies the segment register by 0x10 (16 decimal) and adds an offset the answer is: because the designers chose so.

Next you will ask why did they choose that. A 16bit segment register can hold values from 0 to 65535. Multiply that by 16 and you get addresses from 0 to 1048575, which is 1MB. 1MB is a nice amount of memory to access.

Other architectures may have different multipliers, even non-constant ones. But they will most likely always be powers of 2.

Answer (score 3):

In order to understand that design decision we need step back to the 1974.
Back then we didn't have the miniaturization of nowadays, the number of pins that could be manufactured in a package was quite small.

The 1974 is the year when Intel just introduced the 8080, a chip with a 16 bit address bus, meaning that at most 64 KiB of memory was addressable.
The 8080 however had mostly 8 bit register, so the programmer usually needed to pair two register to form a 16 bit address.

Meanwhile in 1976 the design of a new chip, the 8086, started.
Designers realized that 64 KiB of memory was too low, so they decided to increment the number of pins dedicated to memory addressing, however there were still heavy limitations on the pins number of a chip package.
For this new chip, they settled for 20 bits addresses, or 1 MiB of addressable memory.
When considering why 20 bits we enter a cycle of causes-effects, we need to consider, among other, two important factors:

1. The pin count. It must be as low as possible.
2. The size of the registers. How do you make a 20 bit number with 16 bit numbers?

16 bit were not enough so they needed more bits, easiest solution would have been to use 32 bit, pairing two registers.
But 32 bits were way too much!
The next obvious choice was 24, 16 + 8, as it is a multiple of 8 (a byte).
However 24 bits were still too much.
According to [Intel 8008 to 8086 by Stephen P. Morse et a, Pag. 17](http://www.stevemorse.org/8086history/8086history.doc) they considered this hypothesis but was rejected.
If they cannot have a size multiple of a 8, they could at least have one multiple of 4 (a nibble).
So they settled for 20 bits.

Now a question arose: How do you make a 20 bits number with 16 bit numbers?
The Intel designers chose for the well known segmentation mechanism: **one of the number (the segment) is shifted left by 4 (multiplied by 16, or 10h) before both are added together**.

A more straightforward way would have been to take the extra 4 bits of the address directly from the low nibble of the segment register.
They may have rejected this for various reasons, for example: *a)* it wastes 12 bits of the segment *b)* maybe  it couldn't reuse any ALU component *c)* it doesn't allow address aliasing.

One way or another, the choice was made and as a consequence every x86 compatible CPU need to implement this segmentation model, it's an historical legacy.
This model have been extended since the 80286 and practically deprecated for the x64 processor.